# Is there a web resource available to browse LEGO Minifig head designs?

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

I am curious if there is a minifig browser or gallery that allows you to view and identify LEGO heads created over time? Ideally, this resource would also list the date the minifig head was first available.

Brickset seems to have a minifig browser, but not specifically an option to browse by "head" types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find all the minifigs heads ever made, with the date of release, in the BrickLink catalog: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&catString=238&catType=P&v=2

Please note that I have already sorted the minifigs heads in the link above by year released, however on the first two pages of the results you will see heads where the year is not applied yet. These are new minifigs heads and the sorting and cataloguing haven't bee finished yet. You will start to see the yearly results on page 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can try firestartoys.com. They sort minifig heads by theme. I hope this helps!